# How to highlight/hover/click a selected group of consecutive row cells in HTML table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to create an HTML table that allows highlighting/hovering/clicking on a group of consecutive row cells as one. Is there a way to group them with a wrapper element so that they react to a single hover/click event?

I tried to wrap them in tbody/colgroup tags but that disturbs the layout of the table. Whatever wrappers I tried like div or span they disrupt the table alignment.

This is the original HTML table

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">41.01</span></td>
      <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">43.357</span></td>
      <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">115</span></td>
      <td class="td-body td-border-right"><span class="td-value">+2.56</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">12.10</span></td>
      <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">23.80</span></td>
      <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">3.49</span></td>
      <td class="td-body td-border-right"><span class="td-value">4.05</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">41.78</span></td>
      <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">43.15</span></td>
      <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">114</span></td>
      <td class="td-body td-border-right"><span class="td-value">+1.37</span> 
      </td>
      <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">12.23</span></td>
      <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">23.80</span></td>
      <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">3.49</span></td>
      <td class="td-body td-border-right"><span class="td-value">4.15</span></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Output:

[image: Original table alignment]

The table wrapped in tbody to group the consecutive cells:

```
<table class="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
        <tbody>
        <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">41.01</span></td>
        <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">43.357</span></td>
        <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">115</span></td>
        <td class="td-body td-border-right"><span class="td-value">+2.56</span></td>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
        <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">12.10</span></td>
        <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">23.80</span></td>
        <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">3.49</span></td>
        <td class="td-body td-border-right"><span class="td-value">4.05</span></td>
        </tbody>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <tbody>
        <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">41.78</span></td>
        <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">43.15</span></td>
        <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">114</span></td>
        <td class="td-body td-border-right"><span class="td-value">+1.37</span></td>
        </tbody>
        <tbody>
        <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">12.23</span></td>
        <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">23.80</span></td>
        <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">3.49</span></td>
        <td class="td-body td-border-right"><span class="td-value">4.15</span></td>
        </tbody>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Output:

[image: Disturbed table alignment]

I expect the table to highlighted as below:

[image: Expected table highlighting]

Appreciate your help!

Comment: I don't think  a tbody can be a child of a tr.  There is no valid way of wrapping specific table cells.  As such your only solution would be a js one

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to edit the sintax of a table since it should always be like (table > tbody > tr > td). In your particular case, you may use a jQuery function that let you make that particular highlight like this:

```js
$('tbody tr td').hover(function (e) {
    $('table tbody tr td').removeClass('highlight');
    var startIndex = 4;
    var tr = $(this).parent('tr');
    if ($(this)[0].cellIndex >= startIndex) { //color this and next row                    
        tr.children(':gt(' + (startIndex - 1) + ')').addClass('highlight');
        tr.next().children(':lt(' + startIndex + ')').addClass('highlight');
    }
    else { //Color this and previous row
        tr.children(':lt(' + startIndex + ')').addClass('highlight');
        tr.prev().children(':gt(' + (startIndex - 1) + ')').addClass('highlight');
    }
});
```

```css
.highlight
{
    background-color: #F5F6CE;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table class="table table-sm table-condensed table-bordered">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">41.01</span></td>
            <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">43.357</span></td>
            <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">115</span></td>
            <td class="td-body td-border-right"><span class="td-value">+2.56</span></td>
            <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">12.10</span></td>
            <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">23.80</span></td>
            <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">3.49</span></td>
            <td class="td-body td-border-right"><span class="td-value">4.05</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">41.78</span></td>
            <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">43.15</span></td>
            <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">114</span></td>
            <td class="td-body td-border-right"><span class="td-value">+1.37</span></td>
            <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">12.23</span></td>
            <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">23.80</span></td>
            <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">3.49</span></td>
            <td class="td-body td-border-right"><span class="td-value">4.15</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">41.78</span></td>
            <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">43.15</span></td>
            <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">114</span></td>
            <td class="td-body td-border-right"><span class="td-value">+1.37</span></td>
            <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">12.23</span></td>
            <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">23.80</span></td>
            <td class="td-body"><span class="td-value">3.49</span></td>
            <td class="td-body td-border-right"><span class="td-value">4.15</span></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```